# cant get border on a thumbnail with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do i get a nice border on my thumbnail below? I try to use a container but it means the text runs off the side when used in `md` or `sm` screen widths.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
    <div class="caption-blue thumbnail">
        <div>
            <p>How can i get a border here, i would really like tht but everytime i try the text either runs off the side with a container or no border sows at all ... help!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css for caption-blue

```
   .caption-blue{
        background: rgb(1,165,228);
        font-family: 'myfont';
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us a working example of what you're encountering? the class thumbnail does get a border by default in bootstrap so it should be working. You could just set a `border` on `.thumbnail > div > p`

Comment: You asked this question today.. Where is the example?

Comment: makshh i asked separate question on why text runs off the edge of a div and it seems something to do with container. This is a diff question regarding same code on my border missing. I will edit the question to remove my css class caption-blue

Comment: sodawillow - yea mad but i wanted to make sure i had all had all widths covered, ipad and galaxy tab were causing issues. I will set them all to diff values when i get things tested.

Comment: @sodawillow That's the "beauty" of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS!

You can do it in an external CSS-File or direkt in your div

```
.thumbnail {
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v18z30dn/1/)

Or pure HTML:

```
<div class="caption-blue thumbnail" style="border: solid 1px black;">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v18z30dn/1/)